# Redirecting to another html page after successful login attempt

Tags: javascript, html

So I am using an if else statement for a login form and once you enter the correct login, it should redirect you to another HTML page, but if the information is incorrect, the page just refresh.

function myFunction() {

```
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

if(email == "admin@gmail.com" && password == "user")
{
    window.location.replace("upload.html");     

}
else {
   alert("Invalid information");
    return ;
}
```

}

---

```
    <form id="form" action="" method="GET">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email"  id="email" class="form-control"  aria-describedby="emailHelp" >
          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" >
        </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg shadow" onClick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
     
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, using Javascript to Authenticate a user is a terrible idea, simply because your data is ALL in the client-side.

The issue with your code is that you do not have a Function, which means you are not really doing anything in your HTML you are calling

```
onClick="myFunction()
```

but it does not exist in your JS...

---

This should work:

```js
function auth() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    if (email === "admin@gmail.com" && password === "user") {
        window.location.replace("./upload.html");
        // alert("You Are a ADMIN");

    } else {
        alert("Invalid information");
        return;
    }

}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="" method="GET">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email"  id="email" class="form-control"  aria-describedby="emailHelp" >
          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" >
        </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg shadow" onClick="auth()">Submit</button>
     
      </form>
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `location.reload();`

But you have [other options](https://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html)